# Gradle cannot find dependency in local maven repo while it is there

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to run a gradle task in a project. The task comes from a gradle plugin I forked. Here is the build.gradle of the project that uses the plugin:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
        }
        dependencies {
            // Multi-OS Engine plugin
            classpath group: 'org.multi-os-engine', name: 'moe-gradle', version: '1.3.6-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }

    // Apply plugins
    apply plugin: 'moe'
```

It mainly complains about not being able to find a dependency that clearly is on my file system:

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.multi-os-engine:moe-gradle:1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

On the filesystem:
[image]

I don't blame MOE for this error as I am forking their [plugin](https://github.com/multi-os-engine/moe-plugin-gradle) and trying to run it with modifications so it may be my own fault. I want to understand why Gradle is giving this error.

Here is the full output:

```
    Using already downloaded SDK: C:\Users\Leejjon\.moe\moe-sdk-1.3.6
    :common:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :common:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :common:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :common:jar UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:processResources UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:classes UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:moeMainProGuard UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:moeMainRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:moeGenerateUIObjCInterfaces UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:moeMainDex UP-TO-DATE
    :ios:moeRemoteServerSetup
    MOE Remote Build - REMOTE_HOME=/Users/leejjon
    MOE Remote Build - REMOTE_BUILD_DIR=/var/folders/3m/w6hp3w5n74d8nyybwm9sd7840000gn/T/tmp.8trxgqkq

    =======================================================
     STARTING REMOTE TASK - FILE UPLOAD: prepare - gradlew
    =======================================================

    Local Root: C:\Users\Leejjon\.moe\moe-sdk-1.3.6\tools
        Remote: /var/folders/3m/w6hp3w5n74d8nyybwm9sd7840000gn/T/tmp.8trxgqkq

    \-- gradlew.zip (2.20 MB/s)
    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< [REMOTE TASK DONE] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    ===========================================================
     STARTING REMOTE TASK - COMMAND EXECUTION: install MOE SDK
    ===========================================================

    Command: cd /var/folders/3m/w6hp3w5n74d8nyybwm9sd7840000gn/T/tmp.8trxgqkq && unzip /var/folders/3m/w6hp3w5n74d8nyybwm9sd7840000gn/T/tmp.8trxgqkq/gradlew.zip && cd gradlew && echo 'distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME' >> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties && echo 'distributionPath=wrapper/dists' >> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties && echo 'zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME' >> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties && echo 'zipStorePath=wrapper/dists' >> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties && echo 'distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.5-bin.zip' >> gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties && echo 'buildscript {' >> build.gradle && echo '    repositories {' >> build.gradle && echo '        mavenLocal();jcenter()' >> build.gradle && echo '    }' >> build.gradle && echo '    dependencies {' >> build.gradle && echo '        classpath group: "org.multi-os-engine", name: "moe-gradle", version: "1.3.6-SNAPSHOT"' >> build.gradle && echo '    }' >> build.gradle && echo '}' >> build.gradle && echo '' >> build.gradle && echo 'apply plugin: "moe-sdk"' >> build.gradle && echo 'task printSDKRoot << { print "REMOTE_MOE_SDK_ROOT___1234567890:${moe.sdk.root}" }' >> build.gradle && ./gradlew printSDKRoot -s && cd .. && rm -rf gradlew && rm -f gradlew.zip

    =========================================================
     REMOTE TASK FAILED - COMMAND EXECUTION: install MOE SDK
    =========================================================

    Archive:  /var/folders/3m/w6hp3w5n74d8nyybwm9sd7840000gn/T/tmp.8trxgqkq/gradlew.zip
       creating: gradlew/
       creating: gradlew/gradle/
       creating: gradlew/gradle/wrapper/
      inflating: gradlew/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar  
      inflating: gradlew/gradlew         

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradlew'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not find org.multi-os-engine:moe-gradle:1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.
         Searched in the following locations:
             file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
             file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
             file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
         Required by:
             :gradlew:unspecified

    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradlew'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:488)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:47)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:189)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runRootBuildOperation(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:184)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:674)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:284)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.getScriptClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:70)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:141)
        at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:54)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:129)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        ... 44 more
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.multi-os-engine:moe-gradle:1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
        file:/Users/leejjon/.m2/repository/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.pom
        https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/moe-gradle-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
    Required by:
        :gradlew:unspecified
        at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectDependencyResolver.resolve(ProjectDependencyResolver.java:72)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:575)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:585)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:270)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:244)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveDependencyGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:363)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:338)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:331)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:672)
        ... 54 more


    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 7.18 secs


    :ios:moeRemoteServerSetup FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':ios:moeRemoteServerSetup'.
    > Remote command execution failed

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 11.507 secs
```

Comment: Maybe, you need to rewrite your system path for maven (for example M2_HOME="real path"). For more information: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.multi-os-engine/moe-gradle/1.1.2 and https://github.com/multi-os-engine/moe-plugin-gradle

Comment: I did set my M2_HOME environment variable like you suggested but nothing changes. I had the location of my maven installation C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin already in my path environment variable.